# Starting activity dynamically using DexClassLoader

Tags: android, android-activity, dex

I want to write an app which clicking on a button in it runs an activity from another apk file (not installed on the system). So assume I have Project A, which has Activity A, and Project B with Activity B in it. I want Activity A to dynamically load Activity B at run time (assuming that the APK file for Project B is in the assets directory of Project A, and project A knows which class it has to look for in that APK file.

I know [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) allows you to dynamically load a class from a different DEX file (there is an example of it [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-class-loading-sample/)), but can I do the same thing with APK files which has resources as well? Basically modify the dynamic class loader example in a way that starts a new activity in the system?

Hope the explanation of mine is clear. Any opinion on this is very much appreciated.

Cheers